# Wear app not closed when screen dims

Tags: android, wear-os

My app works pretty good on the wearable (it has communicaton with the phone, animations,...).

But when I open the app, I let the screen timeout happen (so the screen dims and I see the clock), I then open the app again (tap on the clock, scroll to start and choose my app) then my app starts... BUT: When I swipe away my app, the 'previous instance' of the app is below...

How can I fix something like that?

EDIT: manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.test.wear" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"/>
    <activity android:name=".ConfirmationActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post activity declaration from your manifest?

Comment: I edited my post with the manifest of the wearable app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you may need to manually `finish()` your app when the screen dims. I've seen this behavior before mainly in my own apps I think. You can check for screen off/dim using [this code from Nicholas Pomepuy](http://gist.github.com/PomepuyN/cdd821eca163a3279de2)